# HTML - Crop iframe from bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am new in HTML & this is my code yet. What i really need to do is crop height of iframe(100%) from bottom (-50px)" So i need to have my iframe less about 50px from bottom. Thank you so much.

```css
iframe {
  position: fixed;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="iframe">
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am not sure it will work on iframe `height: calc(100% - 50px);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [calc()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) to calculate the height of a iframe element:

> The calc() function performs a calculation to be used as the property value.

```css
.iframe iframe{
  position:fixed; 
  top:0px; 
  left:0px; 
  bottom:0px; 
  right:auto; 
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 50px); /*using calc*/
  border:none; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:999999;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="White">
      <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="iframe">
                <iframe src=""
                ></iframe>
            </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the parent `div` inherit the newly reduced height? i.e. really crop the iframe and avoid the white bar at all?