# Cropping an iframe: Get rid of bottom 100px

Tags: html, css, iframe, crop

My goal is to embed an iframe (I have no control over it) with **variable height** and crop off the bottom 100px.
The code I have so far is this:

```html
<iframe id="booking-content" title="booking-content"
        src="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/SDRRetailConsulting@sdrretail.com/bookings/"
        scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
        style="width: 1024px; height: 100vh; clip-path: inset(0px 0px 100px 0px);
               overflow: hidden; margin:0 auto; border:none;">
</iframe>
```

Unfortunately, `clip-path` generates a white border on the bottom, see:
[image: screenshot]

The working sample with the code to the picture above is [here](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%20%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EHTML%20CSS%20JS%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%3C/head%3E%0A%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%20i$*$d=%22welcome%22%3ECropping%20an%20iframe%3C/h1%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EHow%20can%20I%20get%20ri$*$d%20of%20the%20white%20space%20on%20the%20bottom?%20(due%20to%20clip-path)%3C/p%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ciframe%20i$*$d=%22booking-content%22%20title=%22booking-content%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20src=%22https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wi$*$de_Web%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrolling=%22no%22%20allowfullscreen=%22allowfullscreen%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style=%22wi$*$dth:%201024px;%20height:%20100vh;%20clip-path:%20inset(0px%200px%20100px%200px);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20overflow:%20hi$*$dden;%20margin:0%20auto;%20border:none;%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/iframe%3E%0A%0A%0A%20%20%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E&css=/*%20CSS%20styles%20*/%0Ah1%20%7B%0Afont-family:%20Impact,%20sans-serif;%0Acolor:%20#CE5937;%0A%7D%0A%09%20%20&js=//%20JavaScript%0Adocument.getElementById(%27welcome%27).innerText%20%20=%20%0A%22%20Editors%22;%0A).

Thx a lot! ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127122/html-crop-iframe-from-bottom) question is somewhat related)

Comment: Unfortunately the clip-path... so why use it?

Comment: I don't understand your clip-path - what is the 100px related to (given you can have a viewport of any sort of height)?

Comment: I don't need to use `clip-path` if there are other/better suggestions. I tried with an overlapping footer `div` but no luck either. what would be your suggstion?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `clip-path`, just use `height: calc(100vh - 100px)` :

```css
iframe {
  width: 1024px;
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="welcome">Cropping an iframe</h1>
<p>How can I get rid of the white space on the bottom? (due to clip-path)</p>

<iframe id="booking-content" title="booking-content" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the suggestion! Unfortunately, this fails on my end when using my iframe (ms booking, example: https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/SDRRetailConsulting@sdrretail.com/bookings/)

Answer (score 0):

if what is before the iframe can be variable, meaning height can change, you'll have to calculate all the height till the iframe, and subtract this height to the iframe height (+100).

```js
let h = 0;
let el = document.getElementById('welcome');
el.innerHTML = 'Editors';
while (el.nodeName !== 'IFRAME') {
  h += el.offsetHeight;
  el = el.nextElementSibling;
}
h = window.innerHeight - h - 100;
document.querySelector('iframe').style.height = h + 'px';
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  color: #CE5937;
}

iframe {
  width: 1024px;
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="welcome">Cropping an iframe</h1>
<p>How can I get rid of the white space on the bottom? (due to clip-path)</p>

<iframe id="booking-content" title="booking-content" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```